# Carousel thumbnail responsive mobile display - bootstrap

Tags: mobile, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, thumbnails, carousel

Is there an option to reduce number of thumbnails from 4(desktop) to 1(mobile) display.

The example of carousel thumbnail: http://bootsnipp.com/snipps/thumbnail-carousel

I don't want them to collapse into one vertical row.

Answer (score 1):

The snipp was created by William Woodgate, on 2013-06-09 14:17:36

Get there : [bootsnipp.com/index.php/snipps/thumbnail-carousel](https://bootsnipp.com/index.php/snipps/thumbnail-carousel) and, at the verry bottom of the page, there is a 'Disqus comment form'.

Just fill a request. You'll most probably recieve a ''No, not in a javascript parameter.''

I also saw this webpage about same plugin : http://bootply.com/63984

For your particular context, just add the classes 'hidden-phone' 'hidden-tablet' on those specific elements you want to hide on a tablet or a phone.

```
<ul>
    <li>asdf 1</li>
    <li>asdf 2</li>
    <li class="hidden-tablet">asdf 3</li>
    <li class="hidden-phone hidden-tablet">asdf 4</li>
</ul>
```

So you reduce the number of thumbnails from 4 to .. what you want on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

This might be help you out

[Twitter Bootstrap Vertical Thumbnail Carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18416892/how-to-create-carousel-in-bootstrap-with-vertical-thumbnail/18416893#18416893)

```
MAY THE SOURCE BE WITH YOU
```