# Adding scrollable thumbnails to bootstrap carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I am trying to add a set of scrolling thumbnails to the standard bootstrap carousel. I have found a bootply fiddle here: http://bootply.com/60195 which is almost perfect although if you add more than 6 images, it breaks the layout rather than scrolling the thumbnails from left to right and vice versa.

So far I've tried to isolate the carousel code from a separate thumbnail slider fiddle that I found here: http://www.bootply.com/63984 and integrate it into my main bootstrap files but I just broke it - I think the 2 carousel references were conflicting despite my attempts to re-name and separate the classes of the thumb carousel and the main carousel.

The end result that I'm after is essentially like the flexslider with thumbnails by woothemes but I have found this hard to integrate within the bootstrap framework and lost the responsiveness. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18416892/how-to-create-carousel-in-bootstrap-with-vertical-thumbnail/18416893#18416893  and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095307/carousel-thumbnail-responsive-mobile-display-bootstrap

Comment: Here's an example that works for Bootstrap 3 -- http://bootply.com/79859