# Twitter Bootstrap Vertical Thumbnail Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I search lots on net for Bootstrap Vertical Thumbnail Carousel,
but i didn't find any solution for that, any Idea ?

Comment: then please tell me that what i have to write in question ? thank you :)

Comment: hmmm, Sorry I forgot that silly things, I remove that images from question and past it on answer

Comment: @Mat Now ? I answer on my question first time, so i made this mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a github repository

https://github.com/tutorialdrive/-Bootstrap-Vertical-Thumbnail-Carousel

[image]

[image]

First I use 3 js and 2 css for this

**js**

bootstrap-transition.js

bootstrap-carousel.js

jquery.min.js

**css**

bootstrap.css

style.css

and here is my JQ code for Carousel

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myCarousel').carousel({
            interval: false
        })
    });
```

also I use some ready made vertical Carousel code from here

http://jsfiddle.net/HHsxc/2/

For more, please download it from above github link and don't forgot to fork, also it is in developing status, bug fixing and suggestion are appreciated.