# Bootstrap thumbnail carousel for mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this tutorial for a Bootstrap horizontal carousel with thumbnails showing 4 on a slide. http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/simple-carousel

I would like to have less items show for mobile. I can get it to show 1 on a row but then it stacks vertically. I want them to scroll horizontally just like they do on a large screen. How can I do that?

Each slide is set up like this:

```
<div class="item active">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
            </div><!--.item-->
```

I've seen an answer about hiding specific ones for mobile (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17662129/4597784) but that won't work for me as the images will be pulled from a database and I want to show all images, not just the first one on each slide.

Comment: You could provide 3 different carousels with different setups. One for large screens, one for tablet and one for mobile. Depending on the view port, hide all and show the specific one. if you are on tablet, then hide all and just show the tablet carousel.

Comment: Would recommend you to use the Owl carousel for this purpose: http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/

Comment: @Deka87 How does this integrate with Bootstrap?